# Magento2 Update price automatically when quantity changed on product page

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice, custom-prices

How can I update product price and custom options when user change the quantity ?
If quantity belong to tier price, price should be update accordingly.

Actually I am not able to get the product price and option object in javascript.
So how can I get the price object on custom javascript and reload the price after making custom calculation ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?